# Idris Tutorial - Functions of named implementations in infix form

Tags: syntax, idris

I'm reading through the tutorial for [named implementations](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#named-implementations), which gives `Semigroup Nat` as an example:

```
[PlusNatSemi] Semigroup Nat where
  (<+>) x y = x + y

[MultNatSemi] Semigroup Nat where
  (<+>) x y = x * y
```

If I wanted to use the Plus definition, `(<+>) @{PlusNatSemi} Z (S Z)` works. But is there a way to write this more infix-ly? `Z <+> S Z` complains about a lack of implementation, and neither `Z <+> @{PlusNatSemi} S Z` nor `Z (<+> @{PlusNatSemi}) S Z` work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you need to explicitly define, which named implementations to use.

But `Idris` allows named implementations to be available by default in a block of declarations with `using` notation. Thus, in your example, it's going to be like:

```
[PlusNatSemi] Semigroup Nat where
  (<+>) x y = x + y

[MultNatSemi] Semigroup Nat where
  (<+>) x y = x * y

using implementation PlusNatSemi
  semiPlus : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
  semiPlus x y = x <+> y

using implementation MultNatSemi
  semiMul : Nat -> Nat -> Nat
  semiMul x y = x <+> y
```